# does move.js library work on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, move

maybe someone use [move.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/) library for animations?
I use it, but it seems not working on mobile devices. For example on iphoen 5s safari it works great, but at iphone 4s and meny androids - does not work...

Maybe there is some fixes for that? I looked into source code and see, that there are, seems to be, all needed css properties for mobile devices...but still can not make it work.

Comment: I have made an application using ionic framework and move.js. it is working like a charm on ios but not working properly with Android.

Answer (score 0):

[Move.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/) works on every browser that support CSS3 animations. If you need to support non-CSS3 browsers you can use [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).